# check_for_language always returns false

Tags: django, internationalization

I try language translation using django i18n.
When i try to call the `set_language()` method of i18n then the `check_for_language(lang_code)` always return false.
I done all the steps. Create `locale` directory in project folder & also properly execute the `makemessages` & `compilemessages` command & create `.po` & `.mo` files.

Comment: In general locale should be in app folder, not project.